# Pandas event based data (Data Science)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I got a list of many events with timestamps that are in order and the growth rate of said events needs to be plotted.

The data looks like this:

```
timestamp                   nr  name
2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071  14  kelly
2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071  15  notkelly
2014-05-02 18:47:05.280592  14  alsonotkelly
2014-05-03 18:47:05.332662  26  kelly
```

I am very new to pandas and not a data scientist, but found this: https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_time_series_basics/ and it seems to look right.

At the moment i am so far:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
test = pdtest['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(test['timestamp'])

test.index = df['timestamp']
del test['timestamp']
```

But trying to

```
print(test['2014-05-02 18:47:05'])
```

returns a KeyError even tho, the key is in the dataset. Why is that?

And what would be the correct way to group the events by say 1,3,5 minutes or hours into single data points with the number of events for each time slot? (Without looping over them and binning them manually)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot filter dataframe like this `print(test['2014-05-02 18:47:05'])`
turn timestamp column into index or try loc

```
print(test.loc[test['timestamp'] == '2014-05-02 18:47:05', :])
```

and for grouping time series use resampling check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html)